# How can I quickly move files and folders from a local server to an amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, file-transfer

I'm moving script files from my local server to an amazon EC2 instance using winscp drag and drop, and it's taking too long.  How can I move these files quickly?

Answer (score 2):

Using a UDP file transfer application such as TsunamiUDP (http://tsunami-udp.sourceforge.net/) should help improve the transfer speed quite a bit. Please do note that Tsunami does not encrypt the transfer so you should take care of that before sending the files over.

You'll need to open the relevant ports as specified in the documentation (http://tsunami-udp.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tsunami-udp/docs/USAGE.txt). The default setting is 46224 for both TCP (control) and UDP.

Answer (score 1):

There's no magic here. The bits in that folder need to get from point A to point B *somehow*. It's likely that your internet connection is the bottleneck here. In that case, there is very little you can do to improve file copy performance.

You're using winscp, and I presume you have compression enabled on your client. If that is not the case, try enabling ssh compression.

If that doesn't fix things, there's not much you can do. Perhaps try compressing the folder locally, then transferring it, and then extracting it. You'll get *slightly* better compression that way.

If only *parts* of the folder's contents are changing, you can consider using something like `rsync`, which will allow you to only transfer incremental changes, instead of needing to copy the entire folder each time.